# redisgraph.js - Parsing results of MERGE command

Tags: node.js, redis, cypher, redis-cluster, redisgraph

The [documentation](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/commands/#merge) has the following example to merge relationships *if* all the end-points exist. If the `MERGE` were to be run in the [Javascript client](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph.js), then how can I find out, if the `MERGE` created the nodes and relationships or not? In other words, how can I deduce if the nodes were present beforehand or not?

At the moment, it seems, some methods of [`ResultSet`](https://redisgraph.github.io/redisgraph.js/ResultSet.html) for statistics might have to be used. Any thoughts?

```
GRAPH.QUERY DEMO_GRAPH
"MERGE (charlie { name: 'Charlie Sheen' })
 MERGE (wallStreet:Movie { name: 'Wall Street' })
 MERGE (charlie)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(wallStreet)"
```

Answer (score 0):

the result-set statistics will let you know how many nodes/edges were created, if none that means the pattern existed, otherwise merge created the pattern.

Comment: I ended up using `MATCH....COUNT()` followed by `MERGE`.